# local variable or repeated calls?

Tags: java, performance

I have a very basic question. Which if the below 2 is better performance-wise:

```
if (getSomeValue() != null) {
    processSomeValue(getSomeValue());
}
```

OR

```
String someValue = getSomeValue();
if (someValue != null) {
    processSomeValue(someValue);
}
```

getSomeValue() is a normal getter which does not do anything else.

Comment: I doubt there will be much difference. Perhaps if the getter would perform some heavy duty and this snippet is called some million times in a loop ... Seems like premature optimization to me. Or are you trying to settle a fight on code-style?

Comment: There difference will be irrelevant if it is just a getter.

Comment: It has nothing to do with performance unless `getSomeValue();` is an expensive call.

Comment: normally No 2, but it could be by a trivial amount, or a large amount based upon what `getSomeValue` is doing e.g. DB Look up

Comment: Note that if `getSomeValue()` can be overridden in a subclass, somebody could replace "a normal getter" with something far more expensive.

Comment: @AndyTurner Also, the two calls to getSomeValue could deliver different results (regarding concurrency issues).

Comment: Use the first one if you only need the value once, when you have to use the value twice or more use the second option.

Comment: Thanks @Fildor. Yes. This is more about the code-style. And concurrency is a good point that I can throw in during discussions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A best practice is to always use the 2nd way even you already know that the getSomeValue() is a simple getter. The key thing is that the call might be maintained in the future and changed by someone in the future. Any developer if change the inner code of getSomeValue() may not be aware of the invocation method that you are currently using.